# Error: The keyPrefix reduxPersist: is already in use. Multiple clients cannot share the same keyPrefix

Tags: react-native, apollo-client, aws-appsync

When I am upgrading expo from sdk-33 to sdk-40 version of expo. I am getting this issue, I have aws_appsync dependency in my react-native version 59.10.0.
The problem is occurring when I create new AWSAppSyncClient, I have set "disableOffline" property to true. Still I am getting this issue.

Is this any issue with upgrade expo or react-native dependencies?

> Please help me to upgrade EXPO SDK-33 to SDK-40.

Comment: So far what I understood is that this issue occurs when multiple clients are being created with same keyPrefix, lets say in a scenario while creating react app, if multiple rerenders are happening and client is created inside render function of class component, then client will be created multiple times and it will thow this error. Moving creating appsync client outside the react component solved this error for me.